# Bind mutiple listboxes to single search in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a dilemma here. So I have mutiple expanders stacked on top of one another. Inside each expander is a ListBox, data bound, where each listitem displays a name of an object.

I've bound the search to filter the list items based on their name. However since I have two observable objects, the filtered items and unfiltered, the UI doesn't appear to get populated until someone searches. Whats the best way to fix this. I find it redundant to add items to both lists each time a new Person gets created. Using an mvvm approach.

The two collections are called **People** and **PeopleFiltered**. When i create people I add them to the list called People. When the search is applied it populates the PeopleFiltered list, which is the list the UI is bound to. How can I maintain this list be init to mimic People.

At the end of the day the PeopleFiltered collection should mimic People unless a search is being applied.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="200">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Search:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Background="Gold" Text="{Binding SearchString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>


        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Expander Header="People" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleFiltered}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" Fill="Green" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyBase
    {
        // search text
        private string searchString;
        public string SearchString
        {
            get { return searchString; }
            set
            {
                this.searchString = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchString");
                ApplySearchFilter();
            }
        }

        private void ApplySearchFilter()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchString))
            {
                IsExpanded = false;
                PeopleFiltered.Clear();
                foreach (DisplayItem displayItem in People)
                {
                    PeopleFiltered.Add(displayItem);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // open expanders and apply search
                IsExpanded = true;
                PeopleFiltered.Clear();
                foreach (DisplayItem displayItem in People)
                {
                    if (displayItem.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(SearchString.ToLowerInvariant()))
                    {
                        PeopleFiltered.Add(displayItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // used to to open and close expanders
        private bool isExpanded;
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return this.isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                this.isExpanded = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }

        // data collections for each expander
        private ObservableCollection<DisplayItem> people;
        public ObservableCollection<DisplayItem> People
        {
            get { return people ?? (people = new ObservableCollection<DisplayItem>()); }
            set
            {
                people = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("People");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DisplayItem> peopleFiltered;
        public ObservableCollection<DisplayItem> PeopleFiltered
        {
            get { return peopleFiltered ?? (peopleFiltered = new ObservableCollection<DisplayItem>()); }
            set
            {
                peopleFiltered = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PeopleFiltered");
            }
        }

        // init
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            // People
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name="John" });
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name="Veta"});
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name="Sammy"});
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name = "Sarah" });
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name = "Leslie" });
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name = "Mike" });
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name = "Sherry" });
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name = "Brittany" });
            People.Add(new DisplayItem() { Name = "Kevin" });
        }
    }

    // class used to display all items
    public class DisplayItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    //observable object class
    public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this:- https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/

Comment: Handle TextChanged of TextBox, and Filter the lists. You can see my answer here for filtering a combobox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382459/simple-wpf-combobox-filter/34390669#34390669.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice approach.

Create a `Query` property in your View Model, this will be bound to your filter `TextBox`.

```
private string _Query;

public string Query
{
    get { return _Query; }
    set
    {
        _Query = value;

        Filter();

        //Notify property changed.
    }
}
```

One thing to note here is the `Filter()` method. This will be called every time the property changes, I'll get back to this later. Firstly, make sure your `TextBox` binding is `TwoWay`, it'll look like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Query}" ... />
```

In your View Model, you will need a collection for each `ListBox`.

```
private List<object> _Collection1; //The original collection
private List<object> _FilteredCollection1; //The filtered collection

public List<object> FilteredCollection1
{
    get { return _FilteredCollection1; }
    set
    {
        _FilteredCollection1 = value;

        //Notify property changed.
    }
}

//Some more collections
...
```

It's important to note here that there is a variable for the **original unfiltered collection**. This is important because we want to filter this list into a **new** collection, otherwise we'll just keep filtering over and over and eventually have nothing in the collection.

You'll need to bind the `ItemsSource` property in your `ListBox` to the collection(s).

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection1}" ... />
```

Now, your `Filter` method can simply filter the `_Collection1` variable into the `FilteredCollection1` property.

```
private void Filter()
{
    //Perform the filter here for all collections.
    FilteredCollection1 = _Collection1.Where(x => x.Something == Query);

    //Do the same for all other collections...
}
```

*Note: The above Linq is just an example, I expect yours will be slightly more complicated than that, but you get the idea.*

So. Whenever `Query` gets updated, the `Filter` collection will fire, update the `FilteredCollection` properties which will in turn call property changed and update the view.

---

**Alternative Approach**

Here's another way.

Instead of using a `Filter` method, you can instead put your filter code inside the `get` block in the `FilteredCollection` properties, like this:

```
public List<object> FilteredCollection1
{
    get 
    {
        return _Collection1.Where(...);
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Query` property, simply call `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the collection:

```
private string _Query;

public string Query
{
    get { return _Query; }
    set
    {
        _Query = value;

        //Notify property changed.

        OnPropertyChanged("FilteredCollection1");
    }
}
```

This will force the view to refresh the `FilteredCollection1` property.

Comment: im going to begin building out this demo and ill update my post and notify you when i do.